# Menus in QGIS 3.22 are black and unreadable

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ubuntu

In Ubuntu MATE (21.10) with default dark theme, menus in QGIS are unreadable:

[image]

Answers on SO or other sites deal with with programming Qt, or running a qtconfig that's absent in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the setting in menu Settings -> Options -> General -> Application -> Style. Set it to **gtk2**, and menus will be as in the system.

[image]

Restared QGIS, menus are readable again:

[image]